# Pessoal preciso colocar esse JS que seria um Whatsapp flutuante em uma pagina PHP!

Tags: php, javascript, ponto-flutuante

Pessoal estou tentando coloca esse JS no meu site que esta em PHP
porém tentei as vias que tenho conhecimento porém nada deu certo gostaria do auxilio de você acredito que apenas coloca em um pagina ja consigo colocar em todas um Help Please! segue o JS
Obs:. Ele fica flutuante ok?

```
<==script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {

            whatsapp: "+5583996588383", // Line QR code URL
            email: "site.@gmail.com", // Email
            call: "083996588383", // Call phone number
            company_logo_url: "", // URL of company logo (png, jpg, gif)
            greeting_message: "Tudo bem!", // Text of greeting message
            call_to_action: "Estou Aqui!", // Call to action
            button_color: "#34af23", // Color of button
            position: "left", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
            order: "whatsapp,call,email" // Order of buttons
        };
        var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
<==/script==>  (coloquei == proposital)
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem 2 maneiras para isso , a 1ª:

- Adicione o bloco de código ao final de cada página PHP em que gostaria de visualizar o script.
- Ou adicione esse código a um arquivo separado é utilize a tag: <==script type="text/javascript" src="arquivo.js"==><==/script==> para relacionar seu arquivo com a pagina php em que deseja que ele seja visualizado.

Uma boa forma de testar a implementação, seria utilizando o https://codepen.io/pen.